# AutoHotkey: Writing special characters to a file

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to write the degrees symbol to a file, but I only get the special character question mark symbol. I've tried opening the file with UTF-8 encoding but it doesn't change anything. Is there any way to do this?

This is what I'm trying:

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%

zml := FileOpen("zml.xml", "rw", UTF-8)
zml.write("°")
zml.close()
```

Comment: Unable to replicate this, when I open the file generated in Notepad, it works just fine for me. Some things that might resolve your problem: {Delete the old XML file and allow ahk to regenerate it, restart your computer} Could you possibly give us more info on what program you are using to view whether the `write` has been successful?

Comment: I tried your code and works fine for me. Make sure you're using "AutoHotkeyU64.exe" and try to save your files as UTF-8 with BOM.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation: "If Unicode is supported, Number is a Unicode character code between 0 and 0x10FFFF (or 0xFFFF prior to [v1.1.21]); otherwise it is an ANSI character code between 0 and 255."

`zml.write(chr(176))` works.

176 is ASCII Code for the degree symbol.

`zml.write(chr(0x00B0))` also works.

0x00B0 is Unicode encoding for the degree symbol

```
zml := FileOpen("zml.xml", "rw", UTF-8)
zml.write(chr(176))                      ; also works: zml.write(chr(0x00B0))
zml.close()
```

Whether Unicode encoding is enabled; it could be checked:

```
MsgBox % A_IsUnicode ? "Unicode" : "ANSI"
```

On my machine windows code page: 1252

ahk version: 1.1.33.02

the ahk script files are saved as UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

Quote from [Why are the non-ASCII characters in my script displaying or sending incorrectly?](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#nonascii):

> **Short answer: Save the script as UTF-8 with BOM.**
>
> Although AutoHotkey supports Unicode text, it is optimized for backward compatibility, which means defaulting to the ANSI encoding rather than the more internationally recommended UTF-8. AutoHotkey will not automatically recognize a UTF-8 file unless it begins with a byte order mark.